# Ensuring all child threads end before changing activity

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm new to Android programming and recently learn multi threading.

I've tried using multi threading in my app as per below. There are currently  only two child threads that executes an update to the database which does not affect the UI in any way and runs in the background (as intended)

The child threads are as follows.

```
            //onCreate ...

            Thread t_one = new Thread(new Runnable()
            {public void run() 
            {
            //a line to update database
            }}
                    );
            t_one.start();

    ///the main thread continues executing other
    ///methods before coming to thread t_two

     Thread t_two = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {public void run() 
    {       
    //another line to update database
    }
    }
            );
    t_two.start();
```

The app works fine, but both child treads are quite resource intensive and I have a worry that the child threads might not complete their 'work' in time before the user exits the activity via clicking the button to the next activity.

I have read online about join() (e.g. t_two.join(); after t_two.start(); before starting the next child thread), but I have two issues with this. Firstly, it doesn't work in my case as it gives an error by itself (i.e. "Unhandled Exception type InterruptedException").

Secondly, and more importantly, if starting the second child thread is only conditional upon the first child thread ending/joining the main thread, it seems defeating the original purpose of multi threading.

Is there anyway to check if all child threads running in parallel has successfully completed before allowing the user to exit the activity (via enable the button for them to do so?).

Comment: If you are looking to perform some work that can exist outside of the current activity, you may want to look into using a [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) rather than trying to prevent the normal Activity lifecycle changes.

Comment: I am looking to perform work on another thread. I'm just concerned on if the child thread will terminate before the user moves on to a different activity.

Comment: If you want to perform some work on a background thread that is decoupled from your Activity, an [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html) is probably the best approach